# can we assign a variable with a value of numbers except 1 or any other integer without using loop in ionic 3

Tags: ionic2

here I want  to assign count variable with any set of positive integers except 1 without making it an array or using loop.Can we do this in ionic 2.I tried this and I know this is totally illogical. I don't want it in boolean but in integer.

```
   count:number=1;
   let variable = !count;
```

Comment: I actually want it to assign a value greater then 1 .Like count variable contains all value greater then 1.

Comment: This question looks like to be illogical. You have to check before if count is > from 1. Just this.

Comment: What.You want `count` to hold all values greater than 1? What value do you want `variable` to be like here?'

Comment: yes a variable that can have any value but except '1' .I finally got the solution.I was trying to get the value and then check which is not possible. so i checked the variable using ngIf instead of checking it in typescript.

Comment: well thanks to u all for replying :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is by checking it using

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngIf="count>1"></ion-item>
 </ion-list>
```

in typescript

```
                   count=0;
```